In which cases should the time be transformed when plotting the smoothed scaled Schoenfeld residual plot?
I previously asked this question but didn't get any answers, so I'm reposting it now.
I aim to address the argument transform = '' in R, particularly concerning the smoothed scaled Schoenfeld residual test/plot used to assess the proportional hazards (PH) assumption. I want to understand, statistically, what each transformation does and in which cases one should transform the time to visualize the residual plot.
I understand that the default is transform = 'km', but there are also other options available:
transform='log'
transform='rank'
transform='identity'

I believe I have a grasp of what each means. If my understanding is incorrect, please correct me:
log Used to emphasize early events, as it assigns more weight to them.
rank Utilized to highlight late events, as it assigns greater weight to them.
identity Represents raw time data without any modifications.
However, I'm uncertain about what km does exactly. While it appears to smooth out the time, I'm unsure of its implications.
My specific questions:

From a statistical point of view, could someone elaborate on the details behind each transformation in plain English?
and in which case should I use each transformation to assess the cox.zph() test/plot in R?
Each transformation yield different p-values for the PH assumption. Which p-value should I "trust" based on the chosen transformation?

Thanks in advance!

In my previous question, someone (@J-J-J) commented that I might find some help here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411075/what-does-km-transform-in-cox-zph-function-mean. However, I still need to understand the above three questions.

According to Therneau and Grambsch (p. 132) the proportional hazards (PH) test is "is a score test* for the addition of the time-dependent variable g(t) * X to the model," where X is the covariate and g(t) is the function of time specified by the transform argument. They provide an example:

the test of proportional hazards obtained by the addition of log(t) * X to the Cox model is equivalent to a plot of the scaled Schoenfeld residuals against log(time).

Their general form encapsulated several different suggestions for PH tests that had been proposed previously, as they explain. You can think about g(t) as specifying the shape of variation in log-hazard over time that you want to test for. You can even define your own function if you wish.
The km transformation replaces each event time with the corresponding cumulative event probability over the whole data set, based on the simple Kaplan-Meier survival curve. See this page in addition to the one that you linked.
For which transformation to choose, I'll defer to Therneau and Grambsch (p. 136):

The default choice of the function is tranform = 'km', which uses the left-continuous version of the Kaplan-Meier survival curve (without covariates) to scale the horizontal axis... There is usually very little difference between the km and rank transformations, but the former is less sensitive to censoring patterns. The reason for choosing the K-M transform as the default is that it tends to spread the residuals ... fairly evenly across the plot from left to right, avoiding potential problems with outliers... The other scales are easier for an audience to interpret, however. For long-tailed survival distributions... [log transformation] is often a good choice.

So the choice depends on the type of violation over time that you and your audience care about. You can "trust" the p-value for that particular choice of time transformation, but as you note the transformation choice can affect the apparent significance of the violation.
Instead of perseverating over p-values and transformations, look at the pattern of residuals over some suitable transformation of time that spreads out the residuals reasonably well along the horizontal axis. Then decide if the magnitude of the violation, from the smoothed plot, is large enough to matter at times of interest. If it is, the violation might be telling you something interesting about the underlying biology (in a medical study), for example that the covariate has a large association with failures at early times but not at later times.
Even if PH is violated you still have a type of event-averaged estimate for the log-hazard; if you use robust standard errors you can perform inference on the estimate. See this page. Or consider whether a PH model is the best choice; sometimes an accelerated failure time model can describe the data better.

*It is now, but in early versions of the survival package it was an approximation based on the correlation of residuals with the chosen function of time.

As always, thanks a lot for your incredible explanations! @EdM

One more thing @EdM . Transforming time by km, would I still refer the x-axis as time? or should it be referred to as the cumulative event probability? I'm asking in relation to what to call the x-axis on the plot.

@DeviSita you can call it time. With the labels on the axis, it will be clear that it’s not time on a linear scale. That’s not so different from having an axis that’s log transformed but labeled with the original values. Your figure legend can explain more.
